# IndexError: List out of index in Twitter API streaming?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, twitter-streaming-api

I wrote this script to stream tweets using Twitter API:

```
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import Stream
import random
import os
import twitter
import json
from twitter import *
import logging

ckey = 'xxx'
csecret = 'xxx'
atoken = 'xxx'
asecret = 'xxx'

count = 0

class listener(StreamListener):

    def on_data(self, data):
        global count
        if count <= 10000000000:
            json_data = json.loads(data)

            coords = json_data.get("coordinates")
            tweet = data.split(',"text":"')[1].split('","source')[0]
            time = data.split('"created_at":"')[1].split('","id')[0]
            userid = data.split('"id_str":"')[1].split('","text')[0]

            if coords is not None:
               xy = coords["coordinates"]
               lon = coords["coordinates"][0]
               lat = coords["coordinates"][1]

               print "Time: " + str(time)
               print "Tweet: " + str(tweet)
               print "User ID: " + str(userid)
               print "Coordinates: " + str(xy)

               count += 1

            if coords is None:
               location = data.split (',"location":"')[1].split('","url')[0]

               print "Time: " + str(time)
               print "Tweet: " + str(tweet)
               print "User ID: " + str(userid)
               print "Location: " + str(location)

               count += 1

            return True
        else:
            return False

    def on_error(self, status):
        print status

auth = OAuthHandler(ckey, csecret)
auth.set_access_token(atoken, asecret)

def start_stream():
    while True:
        try:
            twitterStream = Stream(auth, listener(), timeout=30.0)
            twitterStream.filter(locations=[-125,25,-65,48], async=False)
        except: 
            logging.exception('Got exception on main handler')
            continue

start_stream()
```

The problem is that I keep getting IndexError: list index out of range" error quite often:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Username\Desktop\tweepy_test.py", line 67, in start_stream
    twitterStream.filter(locations=[-125,25,-65,48], async=False)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\lib\site-packages\tweepy\streaming.py", line 421, in filter
    self._start(async)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\lib\site-packages\tweepy\streaming.py", line 338, in _start
    self._run()
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\lib\site-packages\tweepy\streaming.py", line 278, in _run
    raise exception
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I'm not sure what went wrong and where should I even look at in order to fix it. I would love to get this fixed to avoid [error 420](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/response-codes) due to too many login attempts in a short period of time. Often times when I get this IndexErrror message, Python throws me error 420 and stops streaming.